# javascript timer

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make the following javascript timer perform two functions with a click of one button only  - click once the timer starts; click again; it stops. click a third time it starts again, and so forth. What am I doing wrong in here? Thank you very much in advance.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var c=0;
        var t;
        var timer_is_on=0;

        function timedCount()
        {
            document.getElementById('txt').value=c;
            c=c+1;
            t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);
        }

        function doTimer()
        {
            if (!timer_is_on)
            {
                timer_is_on=1;
                timedCount();
            }
        }

        function stopCount()
        {
            clearTimeout(t);
            timer_is_on=0;
        }
        function both(){
            doTimer();
            stopCount();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Start count!" onclick="doTimer" />
        <input type="text" id="txt" />
        <input type="button" value="Stop count!" onclick="stopCount()" />
    </form>
<p>
Click on the "Start count!" button above to start the timer. The input field will count forever, starting at 0. Click on the "Stop count!" button to stop the counting. Click on the "Start count!" button to start the timer again.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should format your code as code. Add four spaces before each code line.

Comment: I see two buttons in there. Where's the code that relates to your question?

Comment: @query: People have answered your question, Please take a minute and mark the one you think is the best answer for your question, regards

Answer (score 6):

You don't describe an actual problem, so I'm not quite sure what to respond with, but here's a couple of potentially helpful notes.

The timedCount function is quasi-timed-recursive. This is cool if you're into [continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style), but it's not necessary, probably a little more confusing than it needs to be for JavaScript, and will waste some resources (stack frames) in languages that don't have tail-recursive stack cleanups (don't know if JS has that or not).

Since this is a repeating function execution, you could use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) instead of `setTimeout`, and have a single repeated function call that checks to see if it should increment and re-display the count... something like this:

```
var c=0;
var timer_is_on=false;

function displayCount() {
    document.getElementById('txt').value=c;
}

function count() {
    if(timer_is_on) {
        c=c+1;
        displayCount();
    }
}

var interval = setInterval(count,1000);
```

Now, to address the single-button part of the problem. Let's say there's a single button:

```
<input type="button" value="Start count!" onclick="toggle" />
```

When we click on it, we want that "value" attribute to change, and we want it to flip the `timer_is_on` variable. Let's create a function that does all these things:

```
function toggle() {
    if(timer_is_on) {
       timer_is_on = false;
       this.value = "Start count!";  // `toggle` is invoked by the button's event handler, so `this` is the button
    } else {
       timer_is_on = true;
       this.value = "Stop count!";
    }                   
}
```

So... count is always executing every 1000ms, but it only does anything if timer_is_on, and whether or not timer_is_on is true or false is controlled by `toggle`, which is attached to our button. Little bit simpler, I think.

**UPDATE**

What if we wanted to *not* have the function `count` always running in the background? As Tom Tu points out, this may represent a CPU overhead. I'm not certain it's a measurable one (or that it represents any overhead beyond the timer the browser is probably running to do its own UI updates), but it could be important on some platforms and so it's probably worth addressing.

While we're polishing, I don't much like attaching event handlers through tag attributes myself, or putting variables in the global/window scope if I can avoid it, so I'd probably wrap all our relevant counter setup/processing JavaScript inside one big `setupCounter` function, and also attach the `toggle` function to the `onclick` event of the input button using DOM selection and JavaScript. I'd probably try to only run the `document.getElementById` lookups once each, too.

So, let's say the button input has the id `startstop` but otherwise assume similar markup. I'd probably do something like this:

```
function setupCounter() { 
    var c=0,
        interval,
        counter_display = document.getElementById('txt'),
        button = document.getElementById('startstop');

    function display_count() {
        counter_display.value = c;
    }

    function count() {
        c=c+1;
        display_count();
    }

    function toggle() {
       if(!interval)
          interval = setInterval(count,1000);
          button.value = "Stop count!";
       else {
          clearInterval(interval);
          interval = false;
          button.value = "Start count!";
       }
    }

    button.onclick = toggle;
}
```

Then you'd call `setupCounter` either sometime in the document after both the counter_display and startstop elements have been declared, or assign it to the `window.onload` event or pass it to something like jQuery's `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<form name="f1">
<input type="text" id="but" />
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="timer()" />
<input type="button" value="stop" onclick="stoptimer()" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var count=0;
var x;
function timer(){
x=setTimeout("timer()",1000);
count=count+1;
document.getElementById("but").value=count;
}

function stoptimer(){
clearTimeout(x);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the brackets after doTimer:

```
<input type="button" value="Start count!" onclick="doTimer" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var c=0;
var t;
var timer_is_on= false;

function timedCount() {
    document.getElementById('txt').value=c;
    c++;
    if (timer_is_on) {
        t= setTimeout(timedCount,1000);
    }
}

function doTimer() {
    if (!timer_is_on) {
        timer_is_on=true;
        timedCount();
    }
    else {
        clearTimeout(t);
        timer_is_on=false;
    }
}
```

Attach the `doTimer()` fn to each of your buttons.

Example:  http://jsbin.com/onoge4/3

Changes I made:  use true/false instead of 1/0.

Comment: It may be old, but it just saved my butt!  :o)

Answer (score 0):

1. **The JavaScript**
   *Note the use of `true` and `false` instead of `1` and `0`.*

   ```
   var timer_is_on=false;
   //..
   function doTimer()
   {
       if (!timer_is_on)
       {
           timer_is_on=true;
           timedCount();
       }
       else
       {
           timer_is_on=false;
           stopCount();
       }
   }
   ```
2. **The HTML**
   I see your button is already set to call `doTimer()` `onclick` (however, note that you're missing the parentheses):

   ```
   <input type="button" value="Start count!" onclick="doTimer()" />
   ```
3. **Changing the text of the button**
   First, assign an `id` to the button:

   ```
   <input type="button" id="toggleTimer" value="Start count!" onclick="doTimer()" />
   ```

   Next, modify the JS:

   ```
   function doTimer()
   {
       if (!timer_is_on)
       {
           timer_is_on=true;
           document.getElementById("toggleTimer").value="Stop count!";
           timedCount();
       }
       else
       {
           timer_is_on=false;
           document.getElementById("toggleTimer").value="Start count!";
           stopCount();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Timer with History, Data Storage & Notification:

LIVE DEMO: https://codepen.io/4m6/pen/yLJBXxV
(notification not working in demo, because its inside codepen)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>EZ Timer</title>

    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        html {
            line-height: 1.15;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        main {
            display: block;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 2em;
            margin: 0.67em 0;
        }

        hr {
            box-sizing: content-box;
            height: 0;
            overflow: visible;
        }

        pre {
            font-family: monospace, monospace;
            font-size: 1em;
        }

        a {
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        abbr[title] {
            border-bottom: none;
            text-decoration: underline;
            text-decoration: underline dotted;
        }

        b,
        strong {
            font-weight: bolder;
        }

        code,
        kbd,
        samp {
            font-family: monospace, monospace;
            font-size: 1em;
        }

        small {
            font-size: 80%;
        }

        sub,
        sup {
            font-size: 75%;
            line-height: 0;
            position: relative;
            vertical-align: baseline;
        }

        sub {
            bottom: -0.25em;
        }

        sup {
            top: -0.5em;
        }

        img {
            border-style: none;
        }

        button,
        input,
        optgroup,
        select,
        textarea {
            font-family: inherit;
            font-size: 100%;
            line-height: 1.15;
            margin: 0;
        }

        button,
        input {
            overflow: visible;
        }

        button,
        select {
            text-transform: none;
        }

        button,
        [type="button"],
        [type="reset"],
        [type="submit"] {
            -webkit-appearance: button;
        }

        button::-moz-focus-inner,
        [type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
        [type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
        [type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
            border-style: none;
            padding: 0;
        }

        button:-moz-focusring,
        [type="button"]:-moz-focusring,
        [type="reset"]:-moz-focusring,
        [type="submit"]:-moz-focusring {
            outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;
        }

        fieldset {
            padding: 0.35em 0.75em 0.625em;
        }

        legend {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            color: inherit;
            display: table;
            max-width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            white-space: normal;
        }

        progress {
            vertical-align: baseline;
        }

        textarea {
            overflow: auto;
        }

        [type="checkbox"],
        [type="radio"] {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 0;
        }

        [type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
        [type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
            height: auto;
        }

        [type="search"] {
            -webkit-appearance: textfield;
            outline-offset: -2px;
        }

        [type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
        }

        ::-webkit-file-upload-button {
            -webkit-appearance: button;
            font: inherit;
        }

        details {
            display: block;
        }

        summary {
            display: list-item;
        }

        template {
            display: none;
        }

        [hidden] {
            display: none;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #333;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        #notif-container {
            text-align: center;
            min-width: 400px;
            background-color: red;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            border-radius: 4px;
            position: relative;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 20px;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            margin: 10px;
            display: none;
        }

        .clock-container {
            min-width: 400px;
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            background-color: #1e5f74;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            border-radius: 4px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .clock-container--running {
            background-color: #009400;
        }

        h1 {
            color: #fff;
            margin: 16px;
        }

        .clock {
            display: flex;
            font-size: 50px;
            padding: 0 20px;
        }

        #reset-timer {
            cursor: pointer;
            display: inline-block;
            position: absolute;
            right: 18px;
            top: 18px;
            font-size: 22px;
            font-weight: 600;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: red;
            padding: 2px 6px;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

        .buttons {
            padding: 10px;
            display: flex;
        }

        .time {
            font-size: 50px;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 0;
            border-radius: 4px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            width: 90px;
            background-color: #222;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .time:disabled {
            color: #c1ffd1;
            background: #052400;
        }

        .time-head {
            font-size: 22px;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .colon {
            color: #fff;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }

        .btn {
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: 600;
            background: #888;
            padding: 10px 16px;
            margin: 10px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            color: #555;
            border: 0;
        }

        .btn--active {
            background: #ffd06a;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #000;
        }

        .history-title {
            margin: 10px;
        }

        .history-container {
            background: #333;
            border: 2px solid #222;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px 10px;
            color: #fff;
            border-radius: 4px;
            width: 350px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .history {
            line-height: 1.5;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 2px;
            background: #222;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;">
        <div id="notif-container">
        </div>
        <div class="clock-container">
            <h1>EZ Timer</h1>
            <div id="reset-timer">X</div>
            <div class="clock">
                <div>
                    <div class="time-head">Hours</div>
                    <input min="0" max="99" type="number" value="0" class="time" id="hours" contenteditable="true" />
                </div>
                <div class="colon">:</div>
                <div>
                    <div class="time-head">Minutes</div><input min="0" max="60" type="number" value="0" class="time"
                        id="minutes" contenteditable="true" />
                </div>
                <div class="colon">:</div>
                <div>
                    <div class="time-head">Seconds</div><input min="0" max="60" type="number" value="0" class="time"
                        id="seconds" contenteditable="true" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <input type="submit" value="START" class="btn btn--active" id="start-timer" />
                <div class="btn" id="pause-timer">PAUSE</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; height:100vh; overflow: auto;">
        <h1 class="history-title">History</h1>
        <div class="history-container">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        // To make use single domain/protocol local storage - To avoid multiple storage
        if (location.protocol !== "http:") {
            location.protocol = "http:";
        }
        if (document.domain.substring(0, 4).toLowerCase() == 'www.') {
            window.location = document.URL.replace('//www.', '//');
        }




        // EZ TIMER SELECTORS & FUNCTIONS

        window.ezTimer = {};
        window.ezTimer.isTimerRunning = 'no';
        window.ezTimer.timerH1 = document.querySelector('h1');
        window.ezTimer.clockContainer = document.querySelector('.clock-container');
        window.ezTimer.hrContainer = document.getElementById('hours');
        window.ezTimer.minContainer = document.getElementById('minutes');
        window.ezTimer.secContainer = document.getElementById('seconds');
        window.ezTimer.pauseTimerBtn = document.getElementById('pause-timer');
        window.ezTimer.startTimerBtn = document.getElementById('start-timer');
        window.ezTimer.resetTimerBtn = document.getElementById('reset-timer');
        window.ezTimer.notifContainer = document.getElementById('notif-container');

        window.ezTimer.validateInput = (e) => {
            // prevent: "e", "=", ",", "-", "."
            if ([69, 187, 188, 189, 190].includes(e.keyCode)) { e.preventDefault(); }
        }

        window.ezTimer.validateInput2 = (e) => {
            if (e.target.value.length >= 2) {
                e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, 2);
            }
            if (e.target.value > 60) {
                e.target.value = 60;
            }
        }

        window.ezTimer.resetTimer = () => {
            window.ezTimer.updateHistoryArray('BEFORE RESETTING');
            window.ezTimer.showHistoryOnPage();
            window.ezTimer.setHistoryOnStorage();
            window.ezTimer.hrContainer.value = 0;
            window.ezTimer.minContainer.value = 0;
            window.ezTimer.secContainer.value = 0;
            localStorage.setItem('hrContainer', 0);
            localStorage.setItem('minContainer', 0);
            localStorage.setItem('secContainer', 0);
        }

        window.ezTimer.timerEndNotify = () => {

            var date = new Date();
            var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
            var monthName = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
            var today = `${date.getDate()} - ${monthName} - ${date.getFullYear()}`;

            var hour = date.getHours();
            var min = date.getMinutes();
            var sec = date.getSeconds();
            var time = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;

            var title = 'TIMER DONE';
            var desc = `(${time}) (${today})`;
            if (!window.Notification) {
                console.log('Browser does not support notifications.');
            } else {
                // check if permission is already granted
                if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
                    // show notification here
                    var notify = new Notification(title, {
                        body: desc,
                        requireInteraction: 'shouldRequireInteraction'
                    });
                } else {
                    // request permission from user
                    Notification.requestPermission().then(function (p) {
                        if (p === 'granted') {
                            // show notification here
                            var notify = new Notification(title, {
                                body: desc,
                                requireInteraction: 'shouldRequireInteraction'
                            });
                        } else {
                            console.log('User blocked notifications.');
                        }
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        window.ezTimer.getHistoryArrayFromStorage = () => {
            if (localStorage.getItem('history') != null) { window.ezTimer.history = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('history')); }
            else { window.ezTimer.history = []; }
        }
        window.ezTimer.updateHistoryArray = (when) => {
            window.ezTimer.updateStorageTime();
            var date = new Date();
            var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
            var monthName = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
            window.ezTimer.history.unshift(`WHEN: ${when} <br/> TIMER TIME LEFT: ${localStorage.getItem('hrContainer')}:${localStorage.getItem('minContainer')}:${localStorage.getItem('secContainer')} <br/> TIME: ${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()} ( ${date.getDate()} - ${monthName} - ${date.getFullYear()} )`);
            if (window.ezTimer.history.length > 150) { window.ezTimer.history.length = 150; }
        }
        window.ezTimer.showHistoryOnPage = () => {
            document.querySelector('.history-container').innerHTML = '';
            for (let a of window.ezTimer.history) {
                document.querySelector('.history-container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div class="history">${a}</div>`);
            }
        }
        window.ezTimer.setHistoryOnStorage = () => {
            localStorage.setItem('history', JSON.stringify(window.ezTimer.history));
        }

        window.ezTimer.updatePageTime = () => {
            if (window.ezTimer.secContainer.value >= 1) {
                const x = window.ezTimer.secContainer.value - 1;
                window.ezTimer.secContainer.value = x;
            }
            else {
                if (window.ezTimer.minContainer.value >= 1) {
                    const x = window.ezTimer.minContainer.value - 1;
                    window.ezTimer.minContainer.value = x;

                    window.ezTimer.secContainer.value = 59;
                }
                else {
                    if (window.ezTimer.hrContainer.value >= 1) {
                        const x = window.ezTimer.hrContainer.value - 1;
                        window.ezTimer.hrContainer.value = x;

                        window.ezTimer.secContainer.value = 59;
                        window.ezTimer.minContainer.value = 59;
                    }
                    else {
                        window.ezTimer.pauseTimer('ON TIMER END');
                        window.ezTimer.timerEndNotify();
                        window.ezTimer.pauseTimerBtn.removeEventListener('click', window.ezTimer.runPauseTimer)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        window.ezTimer.updateStorageTime = () => {
            localStorage.setItem('secContainer', window.ezTimer.secContainer.value);
            localStorage.setItem('minContainer', window.ezTimer.minContainer.value);
            localStorage.setItem('hrContainer', window.ezTimer.hrContainer.value);
        }

        // EZ TIMER LOGIC

        if (!window.Notification) {
            window.ezTimer.notifContainer.textContent += 'Browser does not support notifications .';
            window.ezTimer.notifContainer.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
                window.ezTimer.notifContainer.textContent += 'Notification Permission Granted. ';
                window.ezTimer.notifContainer.style.display = 'block';
                window.ezTimer.notifContainer.style.backgroundColor = '#009400';
            }
            else {
                window.ezTimer.notifContainer.textContent += 'Site Notification Permission Blocked. ';
                window.ezTimer.notifContainer.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }

        window.ezTimer.startTimerBtn.addEventListener('click', () => { window.ezTimer.startTimer() }, { once: true });
        window.ezTimer.resetTimerBtn.addEventListener('click', () => { window.ezTimer.resetTimer() });

        if (localStorage.getItem('hrContainer') != null) {
            window.ezTimer.hrContainer.value = localStorage.getItem('hrContainer');
        }
        if (localStorage.getItem('minContainer') != null) {
            window.ezTimer.minContainer.value = localStorage.getItem('minContainer');
        }
        if (localStorage.getItem('secContainer') != null) {
            window.ezTimer.secContainer.value = localStorage.getItem('secContainer');
        }

        window.ezTimer.getHistoryArrayFromStorage();
        window.ezTimer.showHistoryOnPage();

        window.ezTimer.hrContainer.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => { window.ezTimer.validateInput(e) })
        window.ezTimer.minContainer.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => { window.ezTimer.validateInput(e) })
        window.ezTimer.secContainer.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => { window.ezTimer.validateInput(e) })
        window.ezTimer.hrContainer.addEventListener('input', (e) => { window.ezTimer.validateInput2(e) })
        window.ezTimer.minContainer.addEventListener('input', (e) => { window.ezTimer.validateInput2(e) })
        window.ezTimer.secContainer.addEventListener('input', (e) => { window.ezTimer.validateInput2(e) })

        window.ezTimer.startTimer = () => {
            if (window.ezTimer.isTimerRunning == 'no') {
                for (let inpt of document.querySelectorAll('.clock .time')) {
                    inpt.disabled = true;
                }

                window.ezTimer.updatePageTimeEverySec = window.setInterval(() => { window.ezTimer.updatePageTime() }, 1000);
                window.ezTimer.updateStorageTimeEveryMinute = window.setInterval(() => { window.ezTimer.updateStorageTime() }, 60000);

                window.ezTimer.updateHistoryArray('ON START');
                window.ezTimer.showHistoryOnPage();
                window.ezTimer.setHistoryOnStorage();
                window.ezTimer.trackHistory = window.setInterval(() => { window.ezTimer.updateHistoryArray('AUTO'); window.ezTimer.showHistoryOnPage(); window.ezTimer.setHistoryOnStorage(); }
                    , 300000);

                window.ezTimer.timerH1.innerText = 'EZ Timer - Running..';
                window.ezTimer.clockContainer.classList.add('clock-container--running');
                window.ezTimer.startTimerBtn.classList.remove('btn--active');
                window.ezTimer.pauseTimerBtn.classList.add('btn--active');
                window.ezTimer.resetTimerBtn.style.display = 'none';
                window.ezTimer.isTimerRunning = 'yes';
                window.ezTimer.pauseTimerBtn.addEventListener('click', window.ezTimer.runPauseTimer = () => { window.ezTimer.pauseTimer('ON PAUSE') } , { once: true })
            }
        }

        window.ezTimer.pauseTimer = (when) => {
            for (let inpt of document.querySelectorAll('.clock .time')) {
                inpt.disabled = false;
            }
            clearInterval(window.ezTimer.updatePageTimeEverySec);
            clearInterval(window.ezTimer.updateStorageTimeEveryMinute);
            clearInterval(window.ezTimer.trackHistory);

            window.ezTimer.updateHistoryArray(when);
            window.ezTimer.showHistoryOnPage();
            window.ezTimer.setHistoryOnStorage();

            window.ezTimer.timerH1.innerText = 'EZ Timer';
            window.ezTimer.clockContainer.classList.remove('clock-container--running');
            window.ezTimer.pauseTimerBtn.classList.remove('btn--active');
            window.ezTimer.startTimerBtn.classList.add('btn--active');
            window.ezTimer.resetTimerBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
            window.ezTimer.isTimerRunning = 'no';
            window.ezTimer.startTimerBtn.addEventListener('click', () => { window.ezTimer.startTimer() }, { once: true })
        }


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```