# Grails redirect with delay

Tags: grails, redirect, delay

Hey. I would like to do somethinng like this:

- I have a gsp page and a controller than allow the user to register in my website.
- If the registration is sucessfully done, i would like to redirect the page to another page, something like this:

Registration Accepted ... going back in 5 .. 4 ..3 .. 2 .. 1 ..

And after countdown, redirect again to other page. Is there any possible way to do that in a controller ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why force a pointless delay?  Put your message in the [flash](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/flash.html) and redirect immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use javascript for that. It's a client side problem. [Related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767022/javascript-timer)