# Asp.net Checking regularly whether any text was written in the textbox in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, regex

I wanted to check my text box whether it has any data entered or not in the text box regularly if any data as been entered I wanted to change image button. How can I do it please help me here is mycode. Right Now my code works only when page is loaded I wanted to check regularly.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="40px" Width="60%" overflow="hidden" ></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtenderMessages" Watermarktext="Write a message" 
                TargetControlId="TextBox1" WatermarkCssClass="watermark" runat="server">
                </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>

 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert(document.getElementById("test_TextBox1").value.length);
            if (document.getElementById("test_TextBox1").value.length == "") {

                alert(document.getElementById("test_TextBox1").value.length);
            } else {

                alert("something is there");
            }

        });
            </script>
```

Comment: Look into the keyup event

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5767183/173497) to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767022/javascript-timer) on how to use a JavaScript timer. Basically, you can use the JavaScript [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) function to call another function repeatedly.

Answer (score -1):

Please spend some time reading about jQuery, then you will not need to write a lot of plumbing code. Once you have jQuery in your solution, then read about `change` event.

Example

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

Comment: @user3629001 You need to understand how to work with jQuery (and selectors in jQuery) to implement this. Hope this helps.